# How to copy a file from one folder into another using FS in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use Node's fs library to copy a file in one folder into another folder,
But I'm getting an error of `ENOENT: no such file or directory`,
But the file is definitely there.

**My code is as follows -**

```
let fs = require('fs');
let util = require('util');

let copyFile = async() => {

  try {

    let fsCopyFile = util.promisify(fs.copyFile).bind(fs);
    let files = await fsCopyFile('/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/node-crud-app/snippets/sharp/enhancedTest.jpg','/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/node-crud-app/snippets/sharp2/enhancedTest.jpg');

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

copyFile();
```

**Error -**

[image]
[image]

**I also tried -**

```
fsCopyFile('./sharp/enhancedTest.jpg','./sharp2/enhancedTest.jpg');
```

But I'm getting the same error

Comment: Does the folder sharp2 exists?

Comment: Your code is working well. Check file path. copy the path name from folder url instead of write the path. Also check target directory path is exist or not

Comment: @NickLeBlanc sharp2 folder does not exist, I think it should create or overwrite

Comment: @PrakashT I tried `await fsCopyFile('./sharp/enhancedTest.jpg','./sharp2/enhancedTest.jpg');` same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you are using sharp2 directory.But you mentioned in comment sharp2 not exist in the directory.

fsCopyFile doesn't create directory automatically.you should create directory manually.

If you want create directory automatically use Below function:

```
createDirectory(){
   var dir = '';  /* directory name */

   if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
     fs.mkdirSync(dir);
   }
}
```

Comment: doh, I had to create a folder, was able to run the code fine, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is how coping a file using streams.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.createReadStream('source.txt').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('destination.txt'));
```